# Error of PHP? Special letter error

Tags: php, regex

I have this code:

```
$reg = "^[a-zA-ZáčďéíľňóřťšúůýžÁČĎÉÍĽŇÓŘŤŠÚŮÝŽ]{3,20}$"; // At least 3

$string = "šš"; // Only 2 letters

echo preg_match("+".$reg."+", $string);
```

'š' is special letter of The Czech Republic.

It echos 1. Why?
Is it an error of PHP?

Comment: If you're searching for non-ascii characters, you need to include the `u` modifier in your regex pattern.

Comment: @wumm: + is perfectly fine: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: @Reeno, does seem like an odd choice though, does using + as the delimiter then mean you can't use + in the regex?

Comment: @OGHaza true. But odd doesn't mean that's wrong!

Comment: @OGHaza: You can escape it. But if you use / as delimiter you have to escape the / in the regexp... If you don't need + in your regexp, why not use it as delimiter?

Comment: Very true, hadn't thought about that. @STT-LCU don't get me wrong, I'm all for odd.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`u` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).  This will make for a `PCRE_UTF8` compatible match.

```
echo preg_match("+" . $pattern . "+u", $string);
```

This will return `0` for the two character string but 1 if there are 3 characters.

The documentation doesn't explain why, and I can't really find anything on PCRE_UTF8 that explains it simply.  If I had to venture a guess it would be that `{}` applies to bytes by default, but characters with `u` enabled.

Comment: It's probably because of the number of bytes Unicode characters use (i.e. variable-width encoding).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), especially the function signature:

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

it returns an int, 0 for no matches found, 1 for matches found. If you want those matches, assigned to a variable, you'll have to pass a third argument:

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches))
{//if it returns 1, preg_match is true
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Couple that to the fact that you're matching non-ASCII chars, [for which there is a special man page, too](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), you may find it matches with 2 chars, instead of three. So you'll have to resort to the unicodes for those special chars. `š`m for example is matched by `/\u0160/`.
More info on regex + unicode [can be obtained here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)
Unicode chars are *"wider"* (they take up more bytes), but there is an utf8-compatible modifier: `u`:

```
var_dump(preg_match('+'. $pattern . '+u', $string, $matches));
var_dump($matches);
```

Having said that: I've looked around a bit, because PCRE offers script names to match an entire unicode alphabet. A quick glance at the wiki, and some other sources tells me that, perhaps:

```
/\p{Cyrillic}/
```

Might work, but Cyrillic isn't quite the same, anyway, at [the bottom of this page](http://www.biega.com/special-char.html), you can find a table containing all unicode codes for the Czech alphabet.

No way you can blame PHP for this one ;-)
As an aside, stringing together a pattern is all well and good, but there is a safer way: [use the `preg_quote` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
string preg_quote ( string $str [, string $delimiter = NULL ] )
```

In your case:

```
$pattern = preg_quote($reg, '+');
```

Comment: It should return 0, because he is searching for at least 3 characters when he's passing 2

Comment: @STTLCU: Right you are, I've added links to unicode documentation, and I'm checking to see if there is a script name for the czech alphabet... it seems there isn't, though

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the special characters are encoded. If your php file is stored with a single byte encoding it should work, but not if you're using utf-8. If your php file is utf-8 the special characters are actually several bytes. Each of them a valid byte to match in the character class. The same is valid for the $string it. Try:

```
var_dump(strlen("šš")); // should output int(4)
```

The modifier `u` activates the unicode/utf-8 mode for a PCRE pattern and changes the behaviour.

```
$reg = "^[a-zA-ZáčďéíľňóřťšúůýžÁČĎÉÍĽŇÓŘŤŠÚŮÝŽ]{3,20}$";
$string = "šš";    
echo preg_match("(".$reg.")u", $string);
```

This allows some other features, too.

```
$reg = "(^\\pL{3,20}$)u"; 
var_dump(preg_match($reg, "šš"));
var_dump(preg_match($reg, "šššš"));
```

The `\pL`is short for the unicode character property "letter". You can look in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) for more possibilities.